# Showing blob pdf in php

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, pdf, blob

I'm trying to show a PDF file stored in a MySql db like a longblob.

My PHP code is:

```
 $query="select * from reportCrPdf where nome='".$nomeFile."'"; 
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Expires: 0");
 header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 header("Cache-Control: public"); 
 header("Content-Type:application/pdf");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 @read($row["pdf"]);
```

The browser is not able to charging pdf document. What is the issue?

Comment: What is the actual behavior you are getting? Manually writing headers can lead to a number of issues, especially if any output is created prior to setting them.

Comment: loading the document pdf Failed. it could be a plugin's problem?

Comment: issue fixed. In the last line: echo $row[2]; instead of:  @read($row["pdf"]);